# match and add based on character position

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file where I need to match and update based on what number/character is in a fixed position in a file.

if character at position 586 = 5 then insert zero "0" at space 614..
if character at position 586 = 1 then insert zero "0" at space 615

I used sed to add other missing characters and delete/add spaces at various positions, but those were fixed throughout the file.

Answer (score 2):

Could be an option with awk (not tested):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}$586==5{$614="0" $614}$586==1{$615="0" $615}1' inputfile >newfile
$ mv newfile inputfile
```

By setting FS="" , awk delimiter is character.

Comment: thats works perfectly. You rock sir. Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: Note that not all `awk` implementations support an empty `FS`. POSIX leaves the behaviour unspacified for an empty FS

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to do that on every line of the input and that the offset be 1-based and expressed in number of characters as opposed to number of bytes, POSIXly:

```
sed '
  s/^.\{585\}5.\{27\}/&0/;t
  s/^.\{585\}1.\{28\}/&0/'
```

Or:

```
awk 'length >= 613 && substr($0, 586, 1) == "5" {
       $0 = substr($0, 1, 613) "0" substr($0, 614)
       next
     }
     length >= 614 && substr($0, 586, 1) == "1" {
       $0 = substr($0, 1, 614) "0" substr($0, 615)
     }
     {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i -pe '
   m/^.{585}\K5/ && s/.{613}\K/0/;
   m/^.{585}\K1/ && s/.{614}\K/0/;
' inoutfile
```